# Function undefined when run through chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small project I'm working on, and for some reason chrome says that the code below is undefined.

HTML:

```
    <input type="reset" onclick="cleartxt()" class="rset" value="Clear Text"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
    var cleartxt = function() {
       document.getElementById("text").value = "";
    };
```

Can someone help me figure out why this is functioning this way?

Comment: where is the function declared? Is that all the code? inputs do not have closing tags.

Comment: This is the first instance of the function and is activated by the input.

Comment: `cleartxt` would need to be global for that to work. If that variable is assigned from within a function it will be scoped to that function. Try changing it to `window.cleartxt = ...` to be sure.

Comment: My guess is you have something configured that is putting the code in a window.onload or ready, but not seeing where you are running it makes it a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Here is the working snippet.

```js
var cleartxt = function() {
       alert('reset working');
       document.getElementById("text").value = "";
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="reset" onclick="cleartxt()" class="rset" value="Clear Text"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using codepen and since it wasn't working, I thought there was a problem.

Comment: @ArunRedhu your input is different from the OP.. The OP has a closing input tag..

Comment: @ShadowFiend It doesn't matter in Plain `html`, browser understands the same. As it is recommended that input like tags are self closing.

Answer (score 0):

Once you use onclick and call function directly in the dom, you must define a global function and define it before the document fully loaded, eg: put the function definition in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write an input is

```
<input type="reset" onclick="cleartxt()" class="rset" value="Clear Text">
```

without closing tag.

You have to declare the function in the head of your html, and you have tu put the input with the "text" id.

Answer (score 0):

First `<input>` doesn't have a closing tag. Second if you want to use `input type="reset"` no need for javascript but they must be inside a form.. See the snippet below..

```js
var cleartxt = function() {
   document.getElementById("text").value = "";
};
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick ="cleartxt()" class="rset" value="Clear Text" >
<input type="text" id="text" >
<br />
<br />
<p>With form</p>
<form>
   <input type="reset" class="rset" value="Clear Text" >
   <input type="text" id="text" >
</form>
```